# Web.config issue - The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, web-services, web-config, sharepoint-2010

I have ran into a really annoying issue which gives me this error: "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

What I don't get is that it worked perfectly as intedded last friday and the days before that. I have debugged, checked if the webservice files were intact etc. It all fits.

All I did last friday was running a script which ran trough all of the items in my list which contains the article pages and edited their creation date. I don't know if that could have changed something, but that's the only thing I can recall.

---

ASPX.CS

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listId = Request.QueryString["ListID"];
        var itemId = Request.QueryString["ItemID"];

        try
        {
            var spList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[new Guid(listId)];
            var item = spList.GetItemById(int.Parse(itemId));
            var image = (ImageFieldValue)item["PublishingPageImage"];
            var contentType = (string)item["ContentType"];
            var pageLayout = (string) item["PublishingPageLayout"];

            var news = new News
            {
                Title = (string)item["Title"],
                NewsId = item.UniqueId,
                Content = (string)item["PublishingPageContent"],
                ArticleDate = item["ArticleStartDate"] == null ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime)item["ArticleStartDate"],
                PageName = item.File.Name,
                Author = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, (string)item["Author"]).User.LoginName,
                IsArticle = contentType.Contains("Article"),
                PageLayout = GetLayout(pageLayout),
                Image = GetImage(image)
            };

            // Jumps to the WSInstance class.
            WSInstance.InternetInstance().PublishNews(news); // This line throws the exception.
            lblMessage.Text = "News '<i>" + news.Title + "</i>' have been published succesfully to the Internet site.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLogger.LogError("Error occured while publishing news: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace, this);
        }
    }
```

---

WSINSTANCE

```
public static WSIntegration InternetInstance(SPSite spSite)
    {
        // Jumps to the Configuration class.
        var url = Configuration.GetConfigurationValue("Progressive.WS.Internet", spSite);
        ...
        return new WSIntegration
                   {
                       Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain),
                       Url = url
                   };
    }

    public static WSIntegration InternetInstance()
    {
        return InternetInstance(SPContext.Current.Site);
    }
```

---

CONFIGURATION

```
public static class Configuration
{
    public static string GetConfigurationValue(string key, SPSite site)
    {
        var name = site.WebApplication.IisSettings[site.Zone].ServerComment; // This is where it fails and throws the error: "The given key was not present in the dictionary."
        var value = "";
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => { value = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", name).AppSettings.Settings[key].Value; });
        return value;
    }
}
```

---

The section which it gets hold of the data from the web.config file.

```
<appSettings><add key="Progressive.WS.Internet" value="http://shpt02/_layouts/DR/WSIntegration.asmx" /> // This is the key value it cannot find.
<add key="Progressive.WS.Internet.Username" value="user" />
<add key="Progressive.WS.Internet.Password" value="password" />
<add key="Progressive.WS.Internet.Domain" value="domain" /></appSettings>
```

Comment: You are accessing a lot of objects with indexers in your code, can you tell us which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Steve Danner  This line: WSInstance.InternetInstance().PublishNews(news);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that it can't find the site's Zone in the IisSettings dictionary. You should check both the value of the Zone property and the contents of the IisSettings dictionary. They may not contain the values you expect, since you access the IisSettings outside RunWithElevatedPrivileges, ie. with the end user's access rights.

In any case storing application settings in web.config is not the best option in SharePoint, as a web application hosts many site collections and sites. Modifying it causes all the sites to restart and recompile - not a good end user experience!

Check the [Application Settings Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798488.aspx) section in the Sharepoint 2010 Guidance for an alternative way that stores settings in the appropriate site's property bag.

Answer (score 0):

Saw Steve's comment and agree that any pointers to where the error is occuring would be good. Is this Silverlight (or WPF)? If so, it can be a styling name you used in your XAML is not present in the dictionary. Check names carefully and determine if there is an issue here.

Both are possible locations for the issue. Naming issues are often missed as you run through code.

Comment: It's a page which get's loaded into the SharePoint 2010 Silverlight framework. But as I've mentioned, it all worked fine before I ran the controlapplication script to change all dates on the articles.

Comment: By the way, if you scroll horizontal in the code blocks you will find comments telling you where is fails.